# (PyCharm) Tool to understand python code

Tags: python, view, pycharm, inspection, sourceanalyser

we have a programming project on our college in Python and are using PyCharm. There is already an existing code which we have to understand at the first step.

Our project team don't know how to begin analyse the code. Is there a tool for PyCharm which can record the code/function as soon as we run the code? I mean, i want to see which functions calls which other function and get a structure (maybe as a tree) how the functions depends to each other.

This is my first post, i hope to get help here :) Sorry for my english, i'm from germany :P

Comment: Try using the debugger in PyCharm to run the code. Learn about breakpoints to know where to set them up so the code is stopped so you can analyze what is happening at that given moment. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/running-and-debugging.html

Comment: Here's a screencast that introduces the debugger: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQ176FUIyIUZ1mwB-uImQE-gmkwzjNLjP